# ESX 4 question. Checkpoint NGX R70 SPLAT in VM

Tags: vmware-esx

Has anyone been able to get VMXNET3 NIC working in subject VM, seems like it's missing a driver? I'd like the 10G connectivity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install VMWARE tools to get VMXNET3 working correctly. Nothing seems to support it out of the box.